# Writing an isPrime function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, primes, primality-test

```hs
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n = leastDivisor n == n

leastDivisor :: Int -> Int 
leastDivisor n = leastDivisorFrom 2 n

leastDivisorFrom :: Int -> Int -> Int
leastDivisorFrom k n | n `mod` k == 0 = k
                     | otherwise      = leastDivisorFrom (k + 1) n
```

My question would be:

- What design problems does this function have?

Comment: What does `ld` stand for? It's not the logarithmus dualis. So: use proper descriptive names for your functions.

Comment: No, this is not a particularly efficient method. There are [many better approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Computational_methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is too operational. It can be equivalently expressed<sup>(*)</sup> as

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n  =  [n] == take 1 [i | i <- [2..n], mod n i == 0]
```

so it is more visually apparent and immediately clear, a [one-liner](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers_miscellaneous#One-liners) easier to deal with.

Trying it as

```
GHCi> zipWith (-) =<< tail $ filter isPrime [2..]
[1,2,2,4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,4,14,4,6,2,10,2,6,6,4,6,6,2,10,2,4,2,12,12,
4,2,4,6,2,10,6,6,6,2,6,4,2,10,14,4,2,4,14,6,10,2,4,6,8,6,6,4,6,8,4,8,10,2,10,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,12,8,4,
8,4,6,12,2,18,6,10,6,6,2,6,10,6,6,2,6,6,4,2,12,10,2,4,6,6,2,12,4,6,8,10,8,10,8,6,6,4,8,6,4,8,4,14,10
......
```

reveals how slow it is. We could try re-writing it as

```
isPrime n  =  null [i | i <- [2..n-1], mod n i == 0]
           =  none (\ i -> mod n i==0) [2..n-1]
           =  all (\ i -> mod n i > 0) [2..n-1]
           =  and  [mod n i > 0 | i <- [2..n-1]]
```

but `[2..n-1]` is not *that* much shorter than `[2..n]`, isn't it. It should be much *much* shorter, ending *much* earlier than that; and even shorter still, with lots of *holes* in it...

> `isPrime n  =  and [mod n p > 0 | p <- takeWhile (\p -> p^2 <= n) primes]`
>  `primes     =  2 : filter isPrime [3..]`

And the next improvement after that is, [getting rid of `mod`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers) altogether.

---

<sup>(*) this expresses exactly the same computation action as your `leastDivisor n == n` is doing. `take 1` takes just the first of the number's divisors, as a list; its length is necessarily 1; comparing it with the one-element list `[n]` is then equivalent to comparing the first - i.e. smallest - divisor with the number `n`. Just what your code is doing.</sup>

<sup>But in this form, it is (arguably) a clearer code, more visually apparent. At least for me it is so. :)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain a little what's the purpose of this comparison `[n] == take 1`?

Comment: I've added this to the answer. and you're very welcome. :)